# apns payload message json format directly shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

we have implemented apple apns push notification. Configured pem file and device tokens in python. They trigger json payload like this

> {"aps" : {
>    "alert" : "got 1 new offer. To view, please tap here."
>   },"notification_type":"New Offer
>   history","redirect_link”:”offers”}.

we got notification, but the full json shows in message. we need to display only alert message only on notification message

Comment: Use the debugger to verify that the payload is as-shown in your question.  It's extremely unlikely that iOS has a bug that is causing the observed behavior.

Comment: your backend send the wrong APNS

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I think so, but they said json is also a string, why its not work. is there any encode use for sending json?

Comment: Install the provisioning profile that allows you to debug APN issues on the device.  It will show the exact payload the device receives, even before it's delivered to the app.  You can google for the Apple document on APN debugging to find it.

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue... did you ever find the solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

I think for notification to display data instead of json in push try below json

```
{
   "aps":{
      "alert":"This is your message to be displayed",
      "sound":"default",
      "badge":1
    }, 
   "Data":{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}
}
```

The alert content will be displayed in push and the Data Key/Val pairs is your custom data that you can pass in payload and access it in your code.

The code shared above is the working code I have used in most of my API projects.

Comment: I tried like these also, but not works. From python they said, send json as string. I dont know why string json. is there any possible way to send json actual format

Comment: The above is already a json string that you get after json encode function.

Answer (score 2):

Here while you are generating payload you need to create Array in `Python` and than need to apply `json` encode and than pass that json string to APNS server.

In PHP generally developer are doing below code:

```
//Create Payload body with array.    
$body['aps'] = array(
     'alert' => $message,
     'sound' => 'default'
     );

//Convert Payload array to JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

//Pass message to APNS
    $msg = chr(o) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

By This we can achieve APNS message in iPhone.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the data out from dictionary object like

```
NSDictionary *aps = [payload objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSString *alert  = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"]
```

Comment: how to update notification message which poped using this in notifications. parse and using apns payload is ok but how to shown in notification message

Comment: I am not getting what you trying to say, I have answered to get the message, now you can show that message to alert. Please, explain what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1):

plz use this

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
        {
           if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) 
        {
               NSLog(@"Inactive");

           //do your things when you click on notification
        }
        else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
         {

                        NSLog(@"Background");


        }
          else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
          {
          NSLog(@"Active");
     NSDictionary *aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSString *alert  = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"]

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                              alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                              message:alert
                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                                   {
                                              //do on ok press
                                                   }];


                        [alertController addAction:okAction];

                        UIViewController *ob = [self  getTopViewController];
                        [ob presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];




          }
        }




    -(id)getTopViewController{


               UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

                while (topController.presentedViewController) {
                    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
                }
                if (![topController isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

                    return topController;
                }



        }
```

here i am getting top viewcontorller and show alert msg

Answer (score 1):

**You need to get the data from dictionary object and message show on alertview**

```
 - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

                if (userInfo) {
NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
            UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Info" message: message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            }];
            [alert addAction:ok];
            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I feel the responses didn't answer the question. The whole JSON is showing because the payload is not formatted correctly I think. It should look like this:

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "category" : "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
      "alert" : {
         "body" : "Acme message received from Johnny Appleseed", //the message
      },
      "badge" : 3,//This is the little number icon
      "sound" : “chime.aiff" //The sound that will make on the device
   }
}
```

You can find more information here: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting old post, but I had to post this!
After 4 years, no one noticed that the problem in characters! That json is invalid because last 3 double-quotation marks are italic (left/right)! ASCII code of normal double-quotation is 34, while the italic-quote is Unicode char with 3 bytes in UTF8 ([0xE2 0x80 0x9D](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201D)). Moreover, that json is also not valid because it ends with '.'.

So this means that json is written by hand. Generate it through a class or dictionary or any other ways you prefer and you'll be fine, just don't write any form of markups/markdowns by hand. Or at least you can validate your hand-written json by using an online json validator.